# Origin of the term 'blackhead' (as in 'comedo')

Tags: etymology

I'm interested to know the origin of the term **blackhead** to describe a black spot (also called 'comedo'). Does anyone have any clues? Unfortunately the online etymology dictionary only gives information on [comedo](https://www.etymonline.com/word/blackhead).

Bonus question: does anyone have any further information on the spike in usage from 1917 to 1968 shown in [the ngrams of the word](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blackhead&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblackhead%3B%2Cc0)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earliest attestation of "blackhead" in this sense in the Oxford English Dictionary is:

> Blackhead, a boil or pinswell, from the black spot which appears at the apex.
>   <sub>[A dialogue in the Devonshire dialect, by a lady [M. Palmer]: to which is added a glossary, by J.F. Palmer](https://books.google.com/books?id=dPcGAAAAQAAJ&pg=PA30&dq=%22Blackhead%22%22a+boil+or+pinswell%22), 1837</sub>

---

I think I know what's causing the spikes on your graph, but unfortunately it can't really be fixed to get an accurate count. When I look at the different time frames, which are linked at the bottom of that page, plenty of the hits are for other things that are called "blackhead(s)", in particular something also known as [blackhead disease](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histomoniasis) which is a disease of the liver that affects turkeys and other birds. See for example the hits in [between 1940 and 1948](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22blackhead%22&lr=lang_en&tbs=lr:lang_1en,cdr:1,cd_min:1/1/1940,cd_max:12/31/1948&tbm=bks&ei=lQKHW_OSCsmxgge6m57oDg&start=0&sa=N&biw=1436&bih=732&dpr=1). Because Google NGrams doesn't filter out duplicates, I'm also seeing a whole bunch of hits that are for the [same ad](https://books.google.com/books?id=PN8DAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA184&dq=%22blackhead%22) (in different [magazines](https://books.google.com/books?id=3CEDAAAAMBAJ&pg=PA33&dq=%22blackhead%22)) for getting rid of blackheads.

Comment: Also, look at an ngram for both 'acne' and 'blackhead' and notice how the dip in one corresponds to the spike in the other.  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=blackhead%2C+acne&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cblackhead%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cacne%3B%2Cc0